# Java robot class mouseclick with float values possible?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I would like to know if there was an option to use the Java Robot class, to click inbetween pixels.
I did not find anything on this online.

Example:

```
robot.mousePress(float x, float y);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just cast the `float` values to `int`? There is no method to support float parameters. Also pixels are discrete; as you cannot have half a pixel. Also, [mousePress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mousePress(int)) if for pressing _n_-number of buttons.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Half pixels exists if the diplay is scaled

Comment: do you know other options to perform mouseclicks using java?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use float in mouseMove, unless, as remarked in one of your comments, the display is scaled. It would also not make much sense to be able to press half a pixel. You can however convert a float parameter to int, which would work, but would not créate your desired effect.

P.S.: As you've already been told, mousePress is the function that defines which button gets pressed, not where the mouse gets moved to. For this you should use the function mouseMove.